# find text after given string in file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, find

I would like to extract contents of field in file

the way data looks :

```
{"_index":"bk","_type":"account","_id":"1","_score":1,"_source":{"a_n":1,"firstname":"Blake","lastname":"Hess","age":30,"gender":"M","address":"anything Avenue","employer":"anything","email":"anything@gmail.com","city":"anything","state":"anything"}}
```

the desired output

```
Blake
```

Comment: are these 2 separate files ? or one file with one json string per line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `jq` to parse `json` data:

```
jq -r '._source.firstname'
```

With the input data from the question it shows the desired output.

Comment: tried `jq -r .firstname bucket.json`
result is null , null , null etc..

Comment: @I'mV I guess your file `bucket.json` doesn't contain the data shown in the question. Please show (a piece of) your real data.

Comment: @Bodo  edited the question with real data

Comment: @I'mV Now corrected.

Comment: thanks Kusa ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the dedicated JSON parsers mentioned are the right approach. If, for some reason, this doesn't work for you, *and* you really are only interested in this particular field value, then the following is a quick but *dirty*(!!) hack to extract the field value:

```
awk '{split($1,fld,"\"firstname\":\"[[:alnum:]]*\"",sep); print(sep[1])}' <filename> | sed -e "s/\"firstname\":\"//" -e "s/\"$//"
```

This basically uses the pattern `"firstname":"<some string>"` as field separator, prints the *actual* value of the field separator (which would be `"firstname":"Blake"` in your case), and pipes it through `sed` in order to remove the field label, leading double-quote and trailing double-quote.

Again, it is a dirty hack and a dedicated tool should be used whenever possible.